# New LAMP Stack on VirtualBox Ubuntu Forbidden access to webpage

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, file-permissions, lamp

I just installed a LAMP stack on a fresh installation of Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox. I think all went smoothely, the only problem is after i setup a shared directory from my host pc to my /var/www directory, trying to log into any of the site webpages in the browser on Ubuntu through i.e.

```
localhost/index.php/ships
```

Gives me a message "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

I've tried changing ownership of the /var/www directory with

```
sudo chown -R geoff:geoff /var/www
```

and with

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

But when i run "ls -l /var/www" i get: basically for every line of files/folders:

```
drwxrwx--- root vboxsf ....
```

I'm logged in as user geoff. I can't even run ls on /var/www without the sudo command. How do i give myself permission to access all the files in the directory /var/www and also allow me to view pages in the browser that are inside /var/www ? Thanks

Comment: Shared directories on VBox don't allow you to change ownership.

Comment: Before i reinstalled virtualbox and ubuntu, i had it set up so that the shared directory was /var/www and it worked fine. That way i could run my coding environment on my host machine, save the files to the shared directory, and immediately test it by opening it on the testing server. problem is i set it up over a year ago and can't remember how i did it.

Comment: It would be much easier to make the user `www-data` a memebr of the group `vboxsf`, which would give you what you want.